# How to parse the data obtained from $.get() function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I obtained the data from the server using ajax like this: (EDITED)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval(function()
  {
     $.get('/forms/requestProcessor.php', function(data) 
     {
        $("#shout").append(data.question+'<br>');
        alert('Load was performed.');
     },'JSON');
  }, 5000); // 5 seconds
});
```

In the php file,i send data like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $question=$row['Question'];
  $choice1=$row['Choice1']; 
  $choice2=$row['Choice2'];
  $choice3=$row['Choice3'];
  $choice4=$row['Choice4'];

  $return_data->question = $question;
  $return_data->choice1 = $choice1;
  $return_data->choice2 = $choice2;
  $return_data->choice3 = $choice3;
  $return_data->choice4 = $choice4;

  echo(json_encode($return_data));
}
```

It prints "undefined". However, if i point the browser directly to the php file, it shows the data properly in json format

Comment: I made it work using $.getJSON function instead of using $.get() function ... However, as i have indicated above, if i use the echo inside the while loop,its not working... If i use echo outside the while loop, i will get only the last row of my query ... Can someone tell me how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible most easiest way is to return [json_encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) string. so your code would look like this
php:

```
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . "GMT");

    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    header("Content-type: text/x-json");

    echo json_encode($array);

    exit(0);
```

and JavaScript would look like this:

```
 $.get('/forms/requestProcessor.php', function(data) 
 {
  ....
 }, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks as though you are recieving a result string, in which there is no real structure.

if you want, you could use `json_encode()` in your encode whatever data you are wanting to send back in json form, and change the setting of your `$.get()` request to expect json, this way you could simply access them via `data.choice2` etc...

example

```
$return_data->question = $question;
$return_data->choice1 = $choice1;
$return_data->choice2 = $choice2;
...
$return_data->choice5 = $choice5;

echo json_encode($return_data);
```

and then for your `$.get()`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval(function()
  {
     $.get('/forms/requestProcessor.php', function(data) 
     {
        $("#shout").append(data+'<br>');
        alert('Load was performed.');
     },'json');                //<-- added, last argument to expect 'json'
  }, 5000); // 5 seconds
});
```

now the data will be returned in json format, and will be parsed by jQuery because it expects it to be json.

So you could now access the data in your success function with statements like `data.question`, `data.choice1`, etc...

Comment: Hi... It is working if i dont include 'json' in $.get() function ... But, if i include the 'json', nothing is happening

Comment: the jQuery documentation calls for double quotes, but I'm not sure that would cause an issue, but again, if it works as expected without the json argument, I'd just roll with that.

Comment: I tried it both using the single quote and double quote... If i dont use json argument at all, the retrieved data is in json format . It is weird.

Comment: at least it is working as expected, it might be that becasue you are using the shorthand `$.get()` it is using default options to parse the json.

Comment: I am not able to do data.question... It prints "undefined" ... Anyways, thanks for the help... I will try to find out what the problem is.

Comment: right, then it is not working, you just said it was working.  Have you looked at your javascript console after adding `"json"` ?  is it giving you an error?

Comment: Hi, sorry for giving the wrong information. I changed 'json' to 'JSON' and i accessed by data.question. But, now, it prints "undefined" .

Comment: ok, hit `/forms/requestProcessor.php` with a browser and see if you get the json string you expect echoed out.

Comment: I saw the console. It shows "unexpected token in attribute selector: !" .. No line number is given

Comment: Yes, i hit the php file and it shows the data perfectly in json format

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Well, I am using jquery 1.4.4

Comment: please update your question with a copy/pasted version of your working jquery now.

Comment: hi,i am actually encoding the result inside a while loop in php file . Could there be a problem because of that?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  It'll be easier if you were to put it into, say, `<p></p>` pairs, but what you're doing with the data is putting it into DOM nodes.  jQuery is more than happy to let you get the results *out* of those DOM nodes again.

But you could make life easier on yourself if you had the PHP return [JSON](http://json.org), like

```
[ question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4]
```

or even better as

```
{ "question" : "my question text",
  "answers"  : [a1,a2,a3,a4]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you encode the return values of "/forms/requestProcessor.php" into JSON format. 
Then read it from the client with jquery.parseJSON()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

In php you can store response in an array and transform it using json_encode function. Before in jQuery you can retrieve json using $.parseJSON(data)

Answer (score 0):

U have to use `jQuery.parseJSON` for this..

example:

```
"var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );"
```

[click me to know briefly](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)